# Transform table from rows to columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table which looks like this:

[image]

I would like to transform it, so that each row is put as separate column orderered by the field "date". In this case I would like the above data to look like:

[image]

Have in mind that the initial table can have ids with variable number of rows.

Edit: I think I have managed to make some progress by using this query:
"select * from table
pivot(string_agg(step) for rn in (1, 2, 3))"

The end result is: [image]

Is there a way to modify the pivot to dynamically take all values in "rn"?